# Custom property not being set in code-behind

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2008, windows-forms-designer

I have a boolean custom property.  The property changes the behavior of the `Form`, and needs to be executed for intended behavior.  However, if the property is `False`, it's not being set in the auto-generated code-behind (since the default value is `False`, the code-behind generator must think it's not necessary to set it).  It seems that if I set the attribute on the property: `[DefaultValue(True)]` it will generate code-behind saying `MyProperty = False`, but then it won't do it for `True` property values.  I wish to find a way for the property to always be set in code-behind, no matter what the property's value.

It seems my only alternatives are adding in `Sub New()`

```
Me.MyProperty = Me.MyProperty
```

Or else turning the property into an enum, which I don't like either.

It seems that the `DefaultValueAttribute` controls for which values something will be generated and set in code-behind, but I can't figure out a way to make it always generate code-behind.  I was hoping setting an invalid `DefaultValueAttribute` would, but that just seems to make the designer use the last value.

Comment: You want to set it to false if it's false?  Are you just trying to get an event to fire or something?

Comment: Not an event, but side-effect code that must be run.  I suppose it's a question of code semantics, whether it's desirable or not, but it makes sense to me to expose a toggle on a parent form via property, which puts settings on several of its members.

Comment: You could try changing the type of your property from `Boolean` to `Nullable(Of Boolean)` (or `Boolean?`).  That way the default value is `Nothing`, and you should be able to register you changing the value to `False`.  Not sure if this will actually fix your issue or not (and you may have to change it in a few places and possibly handle a null value).

Comment: Thanks, that works too.  I just wish I could figure out a way to make it always generate while keeping it `Boolean`.

Comment: How are you registering that the bool is changed?  Could you force that check on load?  Or maybe toggle it to true then back to false on load.

Comment: It's just whenever the property is set it does the work that needs to be done to change modes in the property itself.